# Cannot resolve symbol 'post'

Tags: android, handler, runnable

The following code is showing the error of cannot resolve symbol post even if `import android.os.Handler;` is used. And also invalid method declaration, return type is required for `Runnable` object.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.txt);

String[] str = new String[] { "72", "71", "70",
        "73", "75", "74", "69", "76", "77", "78" };

final Handler h = new Handler();

h.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Random generator = new Random();
        final int random = generator.nextInt(str.length);
        tv.setText(str[random]);
        h.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The import is correct, the problem seem to be inside the runnable. If you want to run a rask with delay the direct method is postDelay. Two arguments, a runnable and the delay.

h.postDelay(new Runnable..., 1000);

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're calling the method `post()` **outside of a method** in a class.

For example, if your code inside an Activity class,

This is wrong:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final Handler h = new Handler();
    // This is outside a method. It's wrong.
    h.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Random generator = new Random();
            final int random = generator.nextInt(str.length);
            tv.setText(str[random]);
            h.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    });

    ...

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    }
}
```

This is right:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private void generateRandom() {
      final Handler h = new Handler();
       h.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Random generator = new Random();
            final int random = generator.nextInt(str.length);
            tv.setText(str[random]);
            h.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
      });
    }

    ...

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    }
}
```